# Encryption a message which was generated in .NET Core 2.1 under linux adds leading bytes

Tags: encryption, .net-core, public-key-encryption, .net-standard

If have the follwoing situation:

- A Client app runs on Raspian with .NETCore 2.1 (Linux)
- It encrypts a message with a public cert (RSA)
- Sends this encrypted message to a windows server
- This server decrypts the message
- Now the data has 2 more bytes at the beginning of the text!

Example: **Encrypting "Hallo welt" under linux leads to "\u0004\nHallo welt" in windows.**

For me it seems that there is a bug in the linux implementation of the .NETCore encryption, or (maybe padding-problem)?

Encryption is done with

`public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainData, X509Certificate2 certificate) {
  var message = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(plainData));
  message.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber,  certificate));
  return message.Encode();
}`

Decryptiong with:

`public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, X509Certificate2 certificate) {
  var message = new EnvelopedCms();
  message.Decode(encryptedData);
  message.Decrypt(new X509Certificate2Collection {certificate} );
  return message.ContentInfo.Content;
}`

I can also provide an very simple example project if needed...

Comment: It seems to be a known problem... 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in .NET Core and will be fixed in 3.0...

See: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32978